# PHPStorm does not start with new license

Tags: phpstorm

I upgraded my license from a trial to a full license but PHPStorm exits immediately without asking for the new license.

Comment: it's a shame this was downvoted for no reason.

Comment: @VighIosif - self-answered questions are still expected to adhere to Stack Overflow question quality; this question shows no effort of what they did to try and fix it

Comment: You should clarify that with JetBrains. This is not a programming issue.

Comment: @UweAllner True ... and false. This is a phpstorm question, not php (true).  Jetbrains forums are very often as useful as boat-anchors (false). The question is valid as a phpstorm question, the title is useful and the answer informative : it will provide useful guidance to future 'license' victims.

Comment: @UweAllner clarifing a phpstorm issue with jetbrains is just like saying that you have to clarify a git issue with linus... It is a valid question, and it helps developers

Answer (score 2):

There was a deamon still running phpstorm. Run

```
ps aux | grep java
```

and find the java process with a lot of PHPStorm flags, e.g.

```
-Didea.platform.prefix=PhpStorm
```

Kill it. Restart

```
phpstorm.sh
```

It should operate as normal.